# VueJS route params object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am examining someone's code. They have the following in computed:

```
computed: {
        requireParams() {
            return {
                coach: this.coach,
                sid: this.sid
            };
        },
        coach() {
            return this.$route.params.coach || {};
        },
        sid() {
            return this.$route.params.sid || null;
        },
        avatar() {
            if (
                this.coach.profile_pic &&
                this.coach.profile_pic.indexOf("http") !== -1
            ) {
                return this.coach.profile_pic;
            } else {
                return "/images/_avatar.jpg";
            }
        }
}
```

Now in the html template code, coach is referred to multiple times like so

```
<p class="name">{{coach.last_name}}{{coach.first_name}}</p>
```

Could anyone explain how coach is an object being sent in route? I thought only strings could be sent in route like /path/:id would translate to /path/2 so $route.params would give {id: 2}.

But here coach is being accessed in route and it is apparently an object? I don't understand how this is possible

Comment: look in router.js

Comment: computed properties can be injected into the template, you can find the docs here [docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html)

Comment: have a look at my edit please

Comment: Does the code work? Or does `<p class="name">{{coach.last_name}}{{coach.first_name}}</p>` render as `undefinedundefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I am not sure if it is the right way to do it, but Vue lets you to pass an object in your router. If you have vuedevtools you can look at under vue $route section you will see: path, query, params, fullpath, name and meta. In params we can send an object.

For example your route will be like this:

```js
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: '/about/:id',
    name: 'About',
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ '../views/About.vue')
  }
]
```

After lets create a button to push our data between routes.

```js
<template>
  <div class="home">
   
   <button @click="sendObject">send my object</button>
    
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'Home',
  data() {
    return {
      myObj: {
        id: 1,
        name: "George",
        surname: "White",
        number: 123
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    sendObject() {
      this.$router.push({name: 'About', params: {id: this.myObj.id, comingItem: this.myObj}})
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

And finally lets take our item in other route like this:

```js
<template>
  <div class="about">
    <h1>This is my object</h1>
    <div v-for="att in myItem" :key="att.id">
      <div> {{att}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "About",
  data() {
    return {
      myItem : null
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.myItem = this.$route.params.comingItem
  }
}
</script>
```

Dom will be like:

1
George
White
123.

Comment: I thought passing objects in `$route.push({name: xxx, params: {obj: {test: 'test'}}})` wasn't possible because I always got an error and had to stringify the object as the error said only strings can be sent in params. Are you sure the above code works?

Comment: Yes I have tried it and used it before. So I am sure :)